# Get live .html to compare

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I change the content of a div with jquery and want to compare it using this

```
if($("#something").html == "New HTML") //Returns false
if($("#something").html == "Old HTML") //Returns true

console.log($("#something").html) // Returns New HTML
```

I don't know how to explain this more clearly I tried my best. What I need it when I enter the first statement it has to return true. So I need to be able to check it live like console.log does.

http://jsfiddle.net/tWR2H/1/

Comment: Please refer the the jQuery API documentation: [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. I believe you're running into errors because you're calling `.html` instead of `.html()`. I created this example:

JS:

```
if ($("#something").html() == "New HTML") {
    alert("It equals!");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="something">New HTML</div>
```

The alert is triggered.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tWR2H/

Comment: What I meant was more like this http://jsfiddle.net/tWR2H/1/
It needs to show the alert when it turns into New HTML by noticing it changed into New HTML

Comment: Would this do: http://jsfiddle.net/tWR2H/2/ -- Created a function, this can be called when the HTML changes.

Comment: @Xegano you mean you want code to be invoked *automatically* when the content of a specific element is changed? If so, this is currently not possible - there was an HTML5 API for it but it got scrapped because it killed performance.

Comment: Well I just need it to check the value like console.log does since that does give me the right value but I cant do it like "console.log(html) == text" so I need something like that to check it. Making a function of it didnt help either sorry

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear on what you mean by "how console.log does?"

Comment: Well when I change the html with html("New HTML") then console.log() shows me "New HTML" but .html() shows me "Old HTML" the new fiddle you wrote does work the way I want it but on my script it somehow doesn't work that way even if I put it in a function

Comment: This is how I made the function but it doesn't work that way somehow http://jsfiddle.net/tWR2H/4/

Comment: Added a console.log statement, and the function name is case sensitive, fixed, works: http://jsfiddle.net/tWR2H/5/